# VisualStudio.TestPlatform produces many <country>-folders

Tags: visual-studio, build, nunit

In Visual Studio '22 in a Test project with **NUnit**, the V.S. build produces 13 folders with
codes of countries like de, es, fr, it, zh-Hans etc.
Each folder has the same set of 6 dll's e.g.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll

These dll's are also in the root folder and is there a way to avoid these sub-folders in the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict which folders are generated by adding the following line to the project file you're building, inside the `<PropertyGroup>` element:

```
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

And if you fancy French, too:

```
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en;fr</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

Comment: it works, only an empty <SatelliteResourceLanguages/> doesn't work

Comment: @Gerard Well, here's the only official doc I've found about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#satelliteresourcelanguages